# Include and parse file (hosted on external site) as wikitext with MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

With MediaWiki, is there any way to include a text file hosted on another site/server and parse that file as wikitext? Is there any way to include a text file at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to write an extension to do that. [MediawikiInclude](https://gitlab.com/MediawikiInclude/include/blob/master/secure-include.php) is an example, although it might not work with the current version of MediaWiki.